# Insert row with a condition

Tags: sql, sas

I have a table like this one:

```
ID  Gar
 1    A
 2    B
 3    C
 4    A
 5    C
```

and i would like to create this table :

```
ID   Gar  Gar_Corr 
 1    A        1a
 1    A        2a
 1    A        3a
 2    B         B
 3    C         C
 4    A        1a
 4    A        2a
 4    A        3a
 5    C         C
```

What i would like to do is each time there is a variable Gar equal to A, insert into the table 3 new rows with the same ID and Gar, but with a Gar_Corr variable equal to 1a, 2a and 3a.

I tried to merge the first table with one like this :

```
Gar Gar_Corr
  A      1a
  A      1b
  A      1c
  B      B
  C      C
```

but it didn't work as i got the same number of row in the first table than after the merging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you could do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO tbl2 (ID, Gar, Gar_Corr)
SELECT ID, Gar, '1a' FROM tbl1 WHERE Gar = 'A'
UNION
SELECT ID, Gar, '2a' FROM tbl1 WHERE Gar = 'A'
UNION
SELECT ID, Gar, '3a' FROM tbl1 WHERE Gar = 'A'
UNION
SELECT ID, Gar, Gar FROM tbl1 WHERE Gar <> 'A'
```

Comment: While this works, I don't recommend it in SAS; it is much more complicated than the equivalent data step code, and even better is to use table-driven logic (as the OP seems to be trying to do).  I think the "Insert Rows" part of the question is misleading, in any event; what the OP is trying to do is a one-to-many merge/join, not just insert into.

Answer (score 2):

In SAS, you have a few options. You can do a cartesian join:

```
proc sql;
create table want as
  select H.*, G.gar_corr from have H, gar_corr G
   where H.gar=G.gar;
quit;
```

assuming gar_corr is the second table you describe (gar/gar_corr).

You can do this in the data step, but not with merge; you do it with set and key options.  You have to have an index on the table to do it this way; see below.

```
data gar_corr(index=(gar));
input Gar $ Gar_Corr $;
datalines;
  A      1a
  A      1b
  A      1c
  B      B
  C      C
 ;;;;
 run;

 data have(index=(gar));
 input ID  Gar $;
 datalines;
 1    A
 2    B
 3    C
 4    A
 5    C
 ;;;;
 run;

data want;
set have;
do while (_IORC_ le 0); *_IORC_ will be positive when a match is NOT found;
    set gar_corr key=gar;
    if _IORC_=0 then output;
end;
run;
```